# multiple simultaneous key press c#

Tags: c#, keydown

I am programming a game in microsoft visual studio c# and I have to catch lot's of keys simultaneously. I can't detect Q,W,E,R,T,Y at the same time but I can detect Q,W,E,R,T,A.

I tried to use KeyDown and `[DllImport("user32.dll")]` but both of them has the same result. What is the difference between Y and A keys and how can I solve this problem?

```
int code1 = GetVirtualKeyCode(Keys.Q);
int code2 = GetVirtualKeyCode(Keys.W);
int code3 = GetVirtualKeyCode(Keys.E);
int code4 = GetVirtualKeyCode(Keys.R);
int code5 = GetVirtualKeyCode(Keys.T);
int code6 = GetVirtualKeyCode(Keys.Y);
if ((array[code1] & 0x80) != 0 &&
    (array[code2] & 0x80) != 0 &&
    (array[code3] & 0x80) != 0 &&
    (array[code4] & 0x80) != 0 &&
    (array[code5] & 0x80) != 0 &&
    (array[code6] & 0x80) != 0)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("asdasdasd");
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: probably a hardware limitation on your keyboard?

Comment: also, what technology are you using? xna?

Comment: You may not be able to solve this programatically.  I suspect that the keyboard you are using is not capable of addressing that many keys on the same row.  Keyboards support *some* overtype, but you can't really expect them to support mashing all of the keys at the same time.  It's possible that the behavior will vary from keyboard to keyboard.  In short, it's a hardware problem.

Comment: Don't put code in comments.  As you can see, it's unreadable.  There's an edit button below your question.  Click that, paste the code into your question, and indent it four spaces by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button above the editor window.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That doesn't make sense because both combinations have 6 keys.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20449/keyboard-multiple-key-press-problem It'll be a hardware limitation. Some combinations of keys just don't work when you press them simultaneously.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, but the second combination is on two different rows of the keyboard.

Comment: I agree with @RobertHarvey This is a hardware issue, limited by the way the keyboard circuits were designed.

Comment: @RoberHarvey - Makes sense, of course logic would point out, bytes are bytes so both shouldn't work.  We are just going off the author's word the other one worked, would make more sense, if it didn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be related to your keyboard. When I was a gamer, I know that it was a property of keyboards to be able to send multiple keystrokes at the same time; Depending on the keyboard, the number would differ, but also the different combinations would or wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as key rollover. USB keyboards only support a finite key rollover, whereas some cleverly-designed PS/2 keyboards have n-key rollover (many many keys may be depressed at the same time without muting additional keypresses)

Have a read: [Wikipedia Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29)